# Failing the quest "Of Flickering Hearts"

Tags: the-witcher-2

I am attempting to do the "Of Flickering Hearts" quest. En route, I am also doing the search for Tress.

After passing the red bandana to Phillipa, a mob of peasants wish to lynch the prince. Somehow, at that time I am notified that I have failed the "Of Flickering Hearts" quest. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, you need to complete Of Flickering Hearts before giving the bandana to Phillipa, because the quest is given by the Elf Eleyas who will leave with Iorveth when he temporarily leaves Vergen (this happens a little later down the mob quest, but it seems that Eleyas disappears immediately).

In short, *you're doing nothing wrong*, it's only the order that the game has found fault with.